# Eclipse freezes computer java programming android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Every time I run my application on my phone connected to my computer, I have to close eclipse and re-open it. If I don't then in the console it will suddenly fill with a bunch of errors like uncaught exception and the screen will go blank (besides the mouse pointer). At that point I have to hard reboot the computer. Happens almost every time I compile but doesn't always happen at the same time. If I don't shut down eclipse after compiling then the errors start and I have hold down power until the computer shuts down. I tried updated java and am on the current version (Java SE development kit 6 update 26) but still same problem. I even uninstalled all the older versions of Java. Computer is a Dell Studio 1555, processor Pentium dual core T4200 2GHZ, RAM 4GB, 32 bit operating system Windows Vista home premium SP2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did it used to work and then stop?

Comment: Its always been this way since I've installed all the software for android development (probably 6+ months ago). I've just gotten used to it but its very annoying.

Comment: Are you running more than one instance of eclipse?

Comment: Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any crash logs of your eclipse instance? Have you tried editing your eclipse.ini ? Here is mine:

```
-vm
pathToJDK\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: --launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m

Comment: That's mine. Tried changing to your and received multiple errors. Also couldn't find crash logs but maybe not looking in right location.